# Confused about the monero hardforks that spawned xmc monero classic and xmo monero original?

Tags: monero-forks, monero-original, monero-classic

On April 6th, it spawned 3 hardforks of monero supposedly.

- monero original
- monero classic
- monero zero???

I see that monero original is just monero v0.11, but what is up with the other 2? What is the difference? Classic seems to be the same as original as its on the same blockchain. why were there different names?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, they're all the same. There's no actual maintained fork, just the ASICs which didn't switch to another coin continuing mining on their own chain. Three (four I think ?) different people tried to "put a flag" on that in case it amounted to anything, but as far as I know, none of the Monero devs have any interest in maintaining an old version of Monero.

As far as I know, none of those repos merged the key reuse mitigations from Monero, so that tells you a lot about whether anyone is actually spending any time on those forks.

Comment: what is key reuse mitigation?

Comment: They're the patches to record and reuse rings for the same input, as well as maintain a blackball list of outputs which are known spent. See https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/3322